This type parameter might need an `extends` constraint in typescript
Consider these classes and model in typescript.
class ApplicantModel {
  name: string = '';
}

abstract class BaseApplicant {
  abstract handleApplicantData<T>(applicantData: T, isPrimaryApplicant: boolean): void;
}

class Applicant extends BaseApplicant {
  handleApplicantData<ApplicantModel>(applicantData: ApplicantModel): void {
    // Error: This type parameter might need an `extends ApplicantModel` constraint.
    this.processApplicant(applicantData);
  }

  processApplicant(applicant: ApplicantModel): void {
    console.log(applicant.name);
  }
}

I'm getting error:
Argument of type 'ApplicantModel' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ApplicantModel'.(2345)
input.tsx(10, 23): This type parameter might need an `extends globalThis.ApplicantModel` constraint.

Why I need to use extends constraint. Why Argument of type 'ApplicantModel' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ApplicantModel'?
Playground

The problem is that in handleApplicantData<ApplicantModel> ApplicantModel is just the name of the generic type parameter and does not refer to the class/type ApplicantModel as it does in processApplicant(applicant: ApplicantModel). Therefore it complains that ApplicantModel is not assignable to ApplicantModel as the parameter ApplicantModel could of any arbitrary type and therefore needs an extends (that will cause other errors though).

@Palladium02 I think your comment might be an actual answer?

@Palladium02 Thank you so mach. Yeah you're right.

I think @user27425627 is right. you can add the answer for the future use.

I see you've already accepted the other answer but it seems unlikely to me that you want to do it that way. Is handleApplicantData() really supposed to accept anything the caller wants to pass? I'm guessing you really want BaseApplicant to be generic, not the handleApplicantData method. See this playground link. That behaves in a sane way. Can you double check? What are you trying to accomplish with your generics?

@jcalz tbh yes in my real code I made the class generic as you did in the playground. At first I was confused with the weird behaviour but now all is clear. would be happy if you have more idea or answer

@jcalz you can add your point. Accepting/unaccepting an answer is always the case!

I'd say your generics are inappropriately scoped. If BaseApplicant is a specific class with a generic handleApplicantData method, then you're saying that callers of handleApplicantData can specify any type argument for T that they want. Meaning someone could call new Applicant().handleApplicantData(null) if they wanted. But you don't want or expect BaseApplicant or any of its subclasses to be that flexible.
If you want implementers to specify the type argument, then you really want BaseApplicant to be a generic class with a specific handleApplicantData method. That is, move the generic from handleApplicantData to Baseapplicant:
abstract class BaseApplicant<T> {
  abstract handleApplicantData(applicantData: T, isPrimaryApplicant: boolean): void;
}

Now instead of having your subclass try to make handleApplicantData generic somehow (which led to you trying and failing to specify the type argument as ApplicantModel, even though that was just the name of a new generic type parameter), your subclasses can choose what T is:
class Applicant extends BaseApplicant<ApplicantModel> {
  handleApplicantData(applicantData: ApplicantModel): void {
    this.processApplicant(applicantData);
  }

  processApplicant(applicant: ApplicantModel): void {
    console.log(applicant.name);
  }
}

This compiles as desired. An Applicant can only handle ApplicantModel.  Some other subclass of BaseApplicant could handle some other data.
Playground link to code

In your case here:
handleApplicantData<ApplicantModel>(applicantData: ApplicantModel): void {}

ApplicantModel refers to the name of the generic not the type, as
@Palladium02 mentions.
What you want to do is this:
handleApplicantData<T extends ApplicantModel>(applicantData: T): void {}

But since that throws an error as well you would have to do this in the BaseApplicant class:
abstract handleApplicantData<T extends ApplicantModel>(
  applicantData: T,
  isPrimaryApplicant: boolean
): void;

Or if you want to keep it flexible:
abstract handleApplicantData(
  applicantData: unknown,
  isPrimaryApplicant: boolean
): void;

This would still allow you to declare the function as generic in the subclass.
Final code would be:
class ApplicantModel {
  name: string = '';
}

abstract class BaseApplicant {
  abstract handleApplicantData(applicantData: unknown, isPrimaryApplicant: boolean): void;
}

class Applicant extends BaseApplicant {
  handleApplicantData<T extends ApplicantModel>(applicantData: T): void {
    this.processApplicant(applicantData);
  }

  processApplicant(applicant: ApplicantModel): void {
    console.log(applicant.name);
  }
}


This doesn't look right to me; the only reason this compiles is because of method parameter bivariance, so it allows some obviously unsafe things like this playground link. Why would BaseApplicant handle unknown? I'd guess that really they want BaseApplicant to be generic like this playground link shows.

That makes sense! I expected the method to have the type of the subclass.
My mistake.
